# Javascript modal to replace prompt?

Tags: javascript

What is the best way to replace

```
var value = prompt("Enter a URL", "http://www.google.com/");
```

by a javascript modal (preferably pure javascript, if not possible then jquery)

Thanks!

Comment: Best way? Well, I guess the answer is jQuery UI dialogs. In pure JavaScript, there's not a lot of point for such simple information... usually I personally just don't show prompts.

Comment: If you can't do it in pure JavaScript you can't do it in jQuery...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to change theway you call it, so it now follows event-driven programming style like that:

```
function prompt(question, callback) {
    // here build a modal/form and after form submit:
    callback(prompt_value);
}
```

And then use it like that:

```
prompt('Enter a URL:', function(result){
    // do something with the result:
    alert(result);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

For better alerts, you can use [bootboxjs](http://bootboxjs.com/examples.html).

For a pure JS modal, you can check [ModaliseJS](https://github.com/AlexisTM/modalise.js) which is compatible with any css classes.

Example of ModaliseJS (change the classes to your design, just keep one `.close`, `.confirm` and `.cancel` as you please) :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Modal example</title>
    <link href="../../dist/modalise.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="../../dist/modalise.js" type="text/javascript">
    </script>
    <script src="app.js" type="text/javascript">
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Example modal 1</h1><button id="openModal">Show the modal</button>
    <div class="mdl mdl-fadein" id="exampleModal">
        <div class="mdl-content mdl-slidein">
            <center>
                <div class="mdl-header mdl-band-primary">
                    <span class="close">X</span>
                    <h2>Example modal</h2>
                </div>
                <div class="mdl-body">
                    <h3>Content modal</h3>
                    input data: <input type="text" class="inputdata"><br>
                </div>
                <div class="mdl-footer mdl-band-primary">
                    <button class="confirm" onclick="return false">Do
                    thing</button><button class="cancel" onclick=
                    "return false">Cancel the thing</button>
                </div>
            </center>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Javascript :

```
var myModal = {}

window.onload = function(){ 

  var btnOpen = document.getElementById('queryData'); // The button to open the modal
  // if btnsOpen is not given, you can simply use myModal.show()
  // Modalise(id, options);
  myModal = new Modalise('exampleModal', {
      btnsOpen : [btnOpen]
    })
    .attach()
    .on('onConfirm', function(){
      console.log(this.querySelector(".inputdata").value);
    });
}
```